# найти в массиве одинаковые значения и сложить в массив

Tags: массивы

Всем привет.
Необходимо найти в массиве одинаковые значения и сложить в другой массив.

```
        $ar = [
            1 => 'один',

            2 => 'два',
            3 => 'два',
            4 => 'два',

            5 => 'три',
            6 => 'три',

            7 => 'четыре',
            8 => 'пять',
            9 => 'шесть',
        ];
// результат ниже

        $arrrr = [
            1 => [2,3,4],
            2 => [5,6]
        ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно собрать обычным циклом и отобрать нужные при помощи array_filter

```
$res = [];
foreach($ar as $k=>$v) {
    $res[$v][] = $k;
}
$res = array_filter($res, function($x) { return sizeof($x) > 1;});
$res = array_map(function($x) { return implode(', ', $x); }, $res);
```

результат

```
Array
(
    [два] => 2, 3, 4
    [три] => 5, 6
)
```

можно сбросить индексы массива, если они не нужны, при помощи array_values()